# Is it possible to show git annotations for all files automatically?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Is it possible to show git annotations for all files automatically instead of having to open them manually in every file ?

Comment: Do you want annotations to be always shown on the screen? Or you want it to load instantly?

Comment: Always shown on the screen. Otherwise a search function that shows the git annotations of the shown line would be just as good. If you want to find out who used a certain pattern in your code you currently have to search for it and then go into each file, right click and show annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This action is time consuming and therefore annotations are not loaded by default.

There is a plug-in to preload the annotations and cache them so that it works faster: [VCS Annotations Preloader](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8514-vcs-annotations-preloader).

Please vote for the feature request to show VCS annotations automatically:

- [IDEA-162018](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-162018) Show VCS Annotations